# Bugzilla reset to DB verfication

Tags: authentication, admin, bugzilla

I recently installed Bugzilla on a server and I was trying to configure it to work with LDAP authentication.

Unfortunately, I accidentally disabled DB authentication in the Parameters area of the admin section and the LDAP settings were not configured properly.

Now I am unable to log back in as the administrator and can't log in at all over ldap because the settings were incorrect.

I am unable to figure out where I can manually restore DB authentication for bugzilla either directly in the DB or in some config file.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the config file /data/params

You will see an entry called user_verify_class, change this to "DB" and you should be able to log in again.

Comment: The file is params.json now and you can select more than one value like:    `"user_verify_class" : "DB,LDAP"`